# Convert int days to months and days using joda

Tags: java, jodatime

Say I have 203 days. I want to convert that number to the string `x months y days` from today. How do I do that using joda time? (of course 203 is just an example, use z if that helps.)

Comment: Unless this is revenge for something else, please explain downvote.

Comment: Probably you got downvoted because: you have showed no efforts to solve this. You have just threw your question without doing any research to accomplish this.

Comment: that's a lot of assumptions @Smit. I got the number of days from joda using `Days.daysBetween` and `LocalDate`. So this downvote smells of arrogance and presumption. Quite a bit hasty there.

Comment: What matters here is that you haven't shown it. I'll remove the downvote if you _show_ what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3093402 Well my friend, just to let you know, I am not the down-voter, I never give downvotes either to question or answer. Second if you have achieved something and still getting the problem then you should have showed here that I have done this but I am not getting this.

Comment: So if we added 20 days to today `12/13/2013` what output would you expect? 20 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Working out the period *starting at a particular date* is pretty easy with Joda Time. For example:

```
public Period getMonthsAndDays(int days, LocalDate start) {
    LocalDate end = start.plusDays(days);
    return new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDay().withYearsRemoved());
}
```

You can then call `Period.getDays()` and `Period.getMonths()`. Just pass in today's date in the relevant time zone (which you need to consider) and you're away.

Comment: Joda takes care of all of that for you. Which is why I specify joda in the OP. The OP clearly states: `from today`. So yes, I am `trying to work out the months and days represented by a given number of days starting at a particular date`. How do I do that using joda?

Comment: @user3093402: Ah, I missed the "from today" - so in that case, use the code I've provided in the answer, specifying today's date (don't forget the time zone) as the second argument. You can get the months and days from the period.

Comment: awesome! awesome! awesome! Your method returns a period. How do I get `x months y days`? I have something, just wondering for something more elegant: `Period p = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDay().withYearsRemoved());
  int months = p.getMonths();
  p.minusMonths(months);
  int days = p.getDays();
  return p + " months " + days + " days";`

Comment: @user3093402: Well yes, you *can* return it as a string - but I'd consider that *vastly* less elegant than returning it as a `Period`, personally. Separate calculation from presentation.